# TSQL turn table rows into columns with column name and value coming from a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server

I have a table with several columns: ID, col1, col2, col3...
I have a second table with columns: ID, type, title

There is a one to many relationship between first and second tables based on ID.

I want to create a view or stored procedure etc that joins them such that I get

ID, col1, col2, col3, type as name of col4 and title as value of col4

The second table could add several columns to the results based on how many records exist on the many side of the relationship.

Any ideas as to what strategy to take?

Comment: Your google search sting is "sql server pivot query".

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I am aware of Pivot and have used it before but I have not been successful in figuring out how to pivot table 2 to the necessary format and then add the results as a set of columns to the first table.

Comment: Too late but, well this blog post link may help you - [SQL Server-How to get column name along with its value as row and display custom column header dynamically using pivot](https://krishnrajrana.wordpress.com/2017/11/14/sql-server-how-to-get-column-name-along-with-its-value-as-row-and-display-custom-column-header-dynamically-using-pivot/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to try a *Dynamic Pivot Query*.  This will allow you to build the columns based on the `type` values in your second table.

There are several ways to get the column names into the format you'll need for the pivot query.. this is one way.

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(type)
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [type] FROM secondTable) st
ORDER BY st.[type]
```

This will give a string in the format of `[Type1],[Type2],[Type3]`.. this allows us to use this string in the `Select` and also the `Pivot` part of the dynamic query.

Since you're doing a join, you need to create a subquery to pivot on, since there will be multiple `ID` columns which aren't allowed in pivots.

So build your query using something like this.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)  
SET @sql = 
    'SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT ft.ID,
            ft.Col1,
            ft.Col2,
            ft.Col3,
            st.type,
            st.value
         FROM 
            firstTable ft
            JOIN secondTable st ON ft.ID = st.ID
    ) t
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Value)
        FOR type in (' + @columns + ')
    ) p
'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

You would of course use `LEFT JOIN` in your subquery if you want all values in the `firstTable` even if they're not in the `secondTable`.

Then you can execute this query using `EXEC(@sql)` or `Execute sq_executesql @sql`.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8e5c1/4)

Comment: Thank You. This does in fact create the exact results I want.  I have to say that this is well ahead of my SQL knowledge.  I will study it and try to learn.